# Solve Surface Area Formula For Radius

Tags: quadratics, inverse-function

Ok.  I have a Surface Area Formula for a cylinder, but I am wanting to solve for the radius.  The only information I have is the height of the cylinder, which is 8 inches.  I know I can use the Quadratic Formula to convert the formula to solve for the radius, but I get stuck when doing the math.

$$ SA=2\pi r^{2}+2\pi rh$$

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just complete the square:

$$ A = 2\pi r^2 + 2\pi rh $$

$$ \frac{A}{2\pi} = r^2 + rh $$

To [complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) on the right-hand side, we need to add $\frac{h^2}{4} $ to both sides:

$$ \frac{A}{2\pi} + \frac{h^2}{4} = r^2 + rh + \frac{h^2}{4} $$

$$ \frac{A}{2\pi} + \frac{h^2}{4} = \left(r + \frac{h}{2} \right)^2 $$

Since $r > 0$ and $h > 0$, we take the positive root:

$$ r + \frac{h}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{A}{2\pi} + \frac{h^2}{4}} $$

$$ r = -\frac{h}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{A}{2\pi} + \frac{h^2}{4}} $$

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but where did you get **h squared over 4**?

Comment: I added it to both sides in the third step, it allows you to factor the right-hand side. Just added a link and a note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

$$A=2\pi r^{2}+2\pi rh$$

then rearrange it:

$$2\pi r^{2}+2\pi hr - A = 0$$

This is quadratic in $r$ with solutions:

$$r = \frac{-2\pi h \pm \sqrt{4\pi^2h^2 + 8\pi A}}{4\pi}.$$

Since the expression under the radical is greater than $2\pi h$ you choose the "plus" root so that the radius is positive:

$$r = \frac{-2\pi h + \sqrt{4\pi^2h^2 + 8\pi A}}{4\pi}.$$

But to solve for the numerical value of $r$ given $h=8$ inches, you'll need more information. You'll need the surface area also to get the value of $r$.